# Conditionally include script for browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, reference, conditional-statements, jquery-events

I have this kind of script code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.grayscale .inactive img').each(function () {
        $(this).wrap('<div style="display:inline-block;width:' + this.width + 'px;height:' + this.height + 'px;">').clone().addClass('gotcolors').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'opacity': 0
        }).insertBefore(this);
        this.src = grayscale(this.src);
    }).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);

    $(".grayscale li").hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.gotcolors').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.gotcolors').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
    });
}, 1);`
```

And I need it in Mozilla Firefox, in Chrome I'm having error with this `grayscale(this.src)`. How can I include this script just for Mozilla Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this without the use of any library. Here's how to do it:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)
{
     //Your code
}
```

Comment: although in normal case, user agent can be used to detect browser software & version, it's better to use feature detection, like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to have more accurate results.

Comment: @HayotIsmatov I am glad I could help. As suggested by Raptor, you can use Modernizr too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JavaScript library I've found for browser detection.

This might [help](https://github.com/ded/bowser)

Simple to use:

```
// Check if browser is Firefox
if (bowser.gecko) {
    console.info(bowser.version); // Log browser version
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `bowser` (the plugin name) instead of `bower`, right ?

Comment: sorry, typo yes it's `bowser`